# bytearrayoutputstream to xlsx pptx doc docx ppt xls file in react correcpted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, download

bytearrayoutputstream to xlsx pptx doc docx ppt xls file in react correcpted

I have a different list file attached. I want to download a single file. My API is working fine. I checked from the Postman, Diff format - xlsx pptx doc docx ppt xls file getting downloaded and I can open it.

Coming to the React UI - When I integrated the API -

npm I used,

```
const FileDownload = require("js-file-download");
FileDownload(MyEncrypetedData, key.attachmentName);
```

File getting downloaded, When I open any format of the file of below extension - .xlsx, .pptx, .doc, .docx, xls file, its corrupted.

Not able to open the file. Any idea? How to fix this?

Any help would be appreciated. Or Any other package, ( Please let me know how to integrate it as well )